# Where can I get Rapid?

Tags: software

I was watching this video by CorridorDigital and I heard them mention Rapid. I can't find it on Google. Could someone link me to it.

Comment: Maybe this? http://www.additive3d.com/home.htm. Seems like it's a set of techniques: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_prototyping

Comment: @EugeneS - that's close, but not quite it.  They are clearly describing a mesh refinement package for converting a point cloud to a minimally complex, solid body mesh.  Such software is used in the rapid prototyping field to generate a solid model for CNC machining or 3d printing and is also used in the 3d graphics arena, but in this case, they appear to be talking about a particular software package.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue I have been running into when searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be RapidForm which has now been bought out (or changed name possibly) to 3D Systems Geomagic.  The website is [here](http://www.rapidform.com/home/).  I found this by looking for mesh refinement software matching the term Rapid and that seemed likely the best match.  In particular, it appears to be GeoMagic XOS.  I don't personally have any experience with the particular software.

Basically the point behind the software is to make refined meshes from a point cloud.  3D scanners like the Kinect don't actually form a mathematical model, instead, they generated large numbers of points at a given distance from the sensor.  These points are formed into a cloud which then has to be modeled into a vector based solid mesh for rendering purposes.

This process is actually incredibly similar to converting a bitmap image into a vector graphic, but it has to be done to produce smooth, solid surfaces in 3d, so it's a bit of a complex and specialized operation.  Software like this allows for the best fit mesh to be found and to ensure that it makes a solid, detailed mesh that doesn't have holes in it that could cause problems with the geometry.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at that and I think that RapidForm is the site. Thanks for the extra info! To spite being pretty knowledgeable in 3D software and graphics, I learned something new today!

Comment: Again, I am not quite sure if that is it but from what you said I think that is it.

Comment: @b2550 - yeah, it's still a guess on my part, but based on the context of what they were describing and based on all I could find in Google searching.  I'd say I'm 95% confident this is what they were talking about, but it certainly isn't a guarantee.